# how to set backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false property using ngx-smart-modal?

Tags: angular7

I want to prevent ngx-smart-modal from disappearing when clicking outside or pressing escape?

I checked in the docs have backdrop, keyboard keyboard property . i set it false but not working .

Any idea how to achieve this using library.

```
<ngx-smart-modal #videoChatModal identifier="videoChatModal" 
        customClass="video-chat" 
        backdrop="false" 
        dismissable="false" 
        closable="false" 
        escapable="false"
        keyboard="false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delclare property in that way and it will work.

```
[backdrop]="false" 
                [dismissable]="false" 
                [closable]="false" 
                [escapable]="false">
```